# Entity Framework Core: Related Object Id doesn't exist in Db

Tags: database, code-first, entity-framework-core

I want create a tree with the one-many relation by using entity framework core.
When I create Node1, NodeId = 1. Then create Node2, NodeId = 2, with ParentId = xxx that doesn't exist in Db. Node2 is successfully create in Db without any problem. I expect an exception would be throw, but it wasn't. I have to check the ParentId if it exists in Db or not. Does Entity Framework do this existence check of ParentId for me? Or, how to let EF do this automatically? I do this check by myself now.

Here is a sample code of my node class:

```
public class Node
{
    public string NodeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ParentId {get; set; }
    public Node Parent {get; set; }

    public ICollection<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

**Update [2017/2/17]**

I know what's going on now !

Originally I expect that the exception will be throw while the DbSet execute the Add() method, but it throws while the DbContex execute the SaveChange method (DbUpdateException).

1. Is it a good choice that let SaveChange method does this examination?
2. Or do this examination before Add?

I think I prefer the 1st. way. Any suggestions or comments?

Comment: Can you add sample of the code through which you are adding entities?
I used Node class exactly you provided and when I tried to add a node with ParentId being non-existent in database it throws exception for me. ParentId=null is allowed but not non-existent.

Comment: It's strange. I open a new project to implement this, and it works great. The db rejects the case that ParentId is invalid. I'll try to find out the difference between these two project. Thanks Smit. I'll update the newest result after figure it out.